# Importing Google Flights results

Tags: excel

I want to analyze the price of air travel per distance (miles). I was thinking to use Excel to copy the results from Google Flights to Excel. I can't copy directly because then the price, carrier name, destination etc are going to be in that same cell.

How do I copy the result to Excel such that price, carrier name, destination in the same cell?
Or is there any other suggestion to how I am going to analyze price of air travel per miles?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and describe how it does not meet your expectation. If you have a string in a cell, you could probably write an Excel formula to parse out each item in the string as the value of different cells.

Answer (score 0):

1) try to open page with IE. With right click on table, there could be a menu item Export to Excel
2) try to import data from page with Data import wizard in Excel
3) try to use "Split columns" option in Excel, if it possible